# Get only uppermost nodes with xPath, child nodes must be excluded

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Using XPath 1.0

```
<div id="master">
    <div someAttr id="1">
        <div someAttr id="1-1">
            <div someAttr id="1-1-1">
                <div someAttr id="1-1-1-1">innermost child</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div someAttr id="2">
        <div someAttr id="2-1">
            <div someAttr id="2-1-1">
                <div someAttr id="2-1-1-1">innermost child</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using this query which selects all nodes having attribute starting with 'some'

```
//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'some')]]
```

I only need uppermost nodes. For example, elements with ids 1 and 2. And if I use same query on element with id 1 then I should get element with id 1-1 etc.

How to achieve this with xpath?

Comment: In XPath 3.0 there's a function outermost() which does exactly what you want, but you need to tell us which XPath version you are using.

Comment: I am limited to XPath 1.0

Answer (score 0):

To get the outer-most nodes only, you can try by filtering out nodes having ancestor with attribute starts with "name" :

```
//*[.... and not(ancestor::*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'some')]])]
```

So the entire Xpath expression looks like this :

```
//*[
      @*[starts-with(name(), 'some')] 
        and 
      not(ancestor::*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'some')]])
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, this will get me elements with ids 1 and 2, however it will not be possible to use same query on element with id 1 to get element with id 1-1